# Oracle Select numbers from an IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking for the best way to select numbers directly from an in clause.

Basically like:

```
SELECT * FROM (2,6,1,8);
```

That doesn't work.  I can do it this way:

```
SELECT Lv FROM (  SELECT Level LV
                  FROM DUAL
                  CONNECT BY Level < 20)
WHERE Lv IN (2,6,1,8);
```

But that seems to be a bit clunky.  Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Is there a particular problem you're trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: It's really one-off pl/sql executions.  Generating loops over certain numbers and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more elegant if you materialize an auxiliary numbers table:

```
SELECT num FROM numbers WHERE num IN (2,6,1,8);
```

And this is also useful when combined with another table.

For instance, I've had a case where I needed to populate large configuration tables with changes from piecewise results:

Big SP or Excel sheet or report identifies missing cost centers in config gives a large set of results which need to be inserted with varying data in some groups.

Paste partial results into a individual comma separated lists:

```
INSERT INTO {stuff}
SELECT {stuff}, 130 as line_item
FROM numbers
WHERE numbers.num IN ({pasted a section of results})

INSERT INTO {stuff}
SELECT {stuff}, 135 as line_item
FROM numbers
WHERE numbers.num IN ({pasted another section of results})
```

Comment: Great idea.  I've used RowNum with ALL_OBJECTS before but it just doesn't feel right.

Comment: What's the use of the numbers table here?  Couldn't one just write "FROM {big construct} WHERE cost_center in ({selection of results})" ?

Comment: Storing all the numbers in a "numbers" table wastes disk space and has no appreciable benefit over the OP's suggestion of querying SELECT Level FROM DUAL CONNECT BY Level < 20. In fact it will be quite a bit less efficient because Oracle will still read all those blocks from disk for the "numbers" table.

Comment: Sorry, to be more accurate: Oracle will still read all those blocks (from disk or the cache).

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp: Sure, I always have a numbers table and use it for all kinds of things like generating data, generating continuous ranges of values for gap analysis, etc.  Appropriately indexed, of course.  I mainly work on SQL Server, and this question was closely related to some inserts I recently had to do in several batches.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
select column_value from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll(1,2,3,4,5));
```

but that actually returns a varchar2. You can create your own TYPE and use that

```
create type tab_num is table of number;
/
select column_value from table(tab_num(1,2,3,4,5));
```

It's also worth looking at the MODEL clause. It looks complicated, but it is very good at generating data

```
SELECT x from dual
MODEL DIMENSION BY (1 AS z) MEASURES (1 x)
  RULES ITERATE (7) (x[ITERATION_NUMBER]=ITERATION_NUMBER+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't explicitly need the IN clause, you could use UNION:

```
  select 2 from dual
  union
  select 6 from dual
  union
  select 1 from dual
  union
  select 8 from dual
```

There is a more elegant variant to INSERT multiple rows into a table:

```
INSERT ALL
   INTO table (col) VALUES ('a')
   INTO table (col) VALUES ('b')
   INTO table (col) VALUES ('c')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

But I don't know a way to do that for a SELECT.